# AWS NLB SSL Termination with ssl backend protocol

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, kubernetes-ingress

I have a use case where I'm terminating SSL traffic on NLB but getting the error

```
The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port
```

I tried setting -

```
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: ssl
```

Which resolved the issue but I'm not able to understand how this is working.
Is the NLB terminating SSL traffic and then again sending an encrypted traffic further?

I'm using nginx-ingress-controller with below annotations for reference.

```
controller:
  service:
    annotations:
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-connection-idle-timeout: "60"
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-cross-zone-load-balancing-enabled: "true"
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:1234:certificate/1234
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: https
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-negotiation-policy: ELBSecurityPolicy-TLS13-1-2-2021-06
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: nlb
```

Comment: *" Is the NLB terminating SSL traffic and then again sending an encrypted traffic further?"* - yes, if backend protocol is set to ssl. Otherwise SSL is only terminated and plain traffic spoken with backend.